# Seeder runs fine the first time but does not do some tasks in the subsequent loops in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, loops, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a multi tenant multi database application where I have a main `DB` which consists of a tenant table and then for each tenant that is created, there is a new `DB` created. I am writing a seed file for this and I am running it 3 times to create 3 Tenants and subsequent 3 `DB`'s for them.

It runs fine the first time. A new tenant is created in the main `DB`. A new `DB` is created using the `username` of the new tenant. The `DB` is also `migrated` with the `Artisan` command call from the code. But in the next 2 loops, the tenants are created in the main `DB` and new `DB`'s are also created for them but the `Artisan` command call does not migrate the `DB`'s.

```
public function run()
{
    $faker = Faker::create();

    // Fetching all tenants
    $tenants = App\Tenant::all();

    // Deleting their databases
    $tenants->each(function($tenant){
        DB::statement('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ' . $tenant->username);
    });

    // Truncating the tenants table itself
    DB::table('tenant')->truncate();

    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){

        $company = $faker->company();
        $description = $faker->text();
        $logo = $faker->imageUrl(50, 50);
        $username = str_random(8);

        \Config::set('database.default', 'archive');

        echo 'Creating tenant ' . $i . "\r\n";

        Tenant::create([
            'name'          => $company,
            'description'   => $description,
            'logo'          => $logo,
            'username'      => $username,
        ]);

        DB::statement('CREATE DATABASE ' . $username);

        \Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $username);
        \Config::set('database.default', 'tenant');

        echo 'Migrating tenant ' . $i . "\r\n";

        \Artisan::call('migrate', [
            '--path' => 'database/migrations/tenants'
        ]);

        echo "\r\n";
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here. It runs perfectly the first time. And then the last two times only the `DB`'s are created but are not migrated. Only the first `DB` is migrated successfully from this. And no error is thrown from artisan.

The command line output is as follows:

```
Creating tenant 0

Migrating tenant 0


Creating tenant 1

Migrating tenant 1


Creating tenant 2

Migrating tenant 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database connection is kept alive in Laravel, which means that it will not switch to new database when you change the database name via `config`. You need to force the background connection to be reconnected by `DB::connection($connection)->reconnect()`.

When running migrations, because Laravel use the database name and the table name to check the existence of the `migrations` table, you need to update the table name of the current connection as well.

In your case:

```
# ...
\Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $username);
\Config::set('database.default', 'tenant');

\DB::reconnect();
\DB::setDatabaseName($username);
# ...
```

Comment: `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'psiqQVD7.migrations' doesn't exist` I am getting this when I am trying the solution. Any idea what is going on? The first table still sets up correctly. The second table doesn't. This error shows up on the Artisan command call.

Comment: I have edited my answer and test it with my local MySQL installation.

Comment: Okay this worked. Wow. But I still don't understand how. Anyway thanks. :)