# How to fetch resource records by dynamically changing DBs in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multi-tenant

So whenever I need to fetch a tenant information for the main superadmin, I set the tenants database value to the one which is to be queried like so:

```
\Config::set('database.connections.tenants.database', $tenant->username);
```

I am able to do this:

```
$users = User::on('tenant')->find(1);
```

But this...

```
$users = User::on('tenant')->all();
```

...gives me an error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()

How will I get back all users from a tenant's database?

**EDIT**

```
public function showUsersForTenant($id)
{
    $tenant = Tenant::findOrFail($id);

    \Config::set('database.connections.tenants.database', $tenant->username);

    \DB::reconnect();
    \DB::setDatabaseName($tenant->username);

    $users = User::on('tenant')->get();

    return response()->json($users, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `on`, you should use `get` instead of `all`:

```
$users = User::on('tenant')->get()
```

In fact, the `all` method calls the `get` internally.

Comment: Although I still have one problem. This is not getting the records from the user table of tenant connection. It just returns me the records from the main DB connection which is already connected. Any idea about that?

Comment: You can use the same approach in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32989103/1399505

Comment: I edited my question to show you the method itself but it is still not working. Where do you think I am going wrong?